# How to nest json in python?

Tags: python, json, django

I'm working on django app and need to pass data from django sql as json to javascript. I'm struggling with nesting one thing. I was able to nest one level but I can't nest second level. While nesting second level, json replaces the value according to itteration instead of appending it. My goal it to obtain the the following effect:

date > [time1 > [1,2,3], time2 > [1,2,3]], date2 > [time1 > [1,2,3]] etc..

At this moment i can't nest more than one time :( Appreciate for help !

```
reserved = Reservation.objects.get(customer=user_info)
        for x in reserved.reservations.all():
            title = x.movie.title
            image = x.movie.image
            date = str(x.date)
            time = str(x.time)
            dates = {date:{}}
            times = {time:{}}
            if title in dic:
                pass
            else:
                dic[title] = {"image":str(image), "dates":{}}
            for y in x.seats.all():
                seats = {y.row:y.number}
                times[time].update(seats)
            dates[date].update(times)
            dic[title]["dates"].update(dates)
```

[CURRENT RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzVvm.jpg)

Comment: Would you display your expected output as a JSON format?

Comment: @BoseongChoi just edited. There should be 2 more hours but as stated json replaces the values according to itteration instead of appending the current itteration

Comment: I don't get it. What is the final result that you want? What does it look like? Show us in JSON format.

Comment: @BoseongChoi I posted the photo under "CURRENT RESULT" and clearly stated that there should be more "hour" under each date. At this moment I'm able to nest only one hour because my loop overwrites the result instead of appending it.